# Delphi Datasnap: How to manually build dataset when using a TDatasetProvider

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset, tdatasetprovider

I would like to manually build the dataset used by a TDatasetProvider to return the data to the client.

The SQL request is taking a long time to run as a query and I am trying to speed up things by splitting the logic in code and using a kbmMemtable to hold my data before returning it to the client.

Can I do this:

kbmMemtable -> TDatasetProvider -> TClientDataset

If this can be done, in what event of my TDatasetProvider should I set the data in the memtable ?

Using Delphi XE

Comment: "kbmMemtable -> TDatasetProvider -> TClientDataset"  Yes.  "in what event"  It doesn't have to be in an event, just before you open the CDS.  But this is a distraction: you would do far better to spend your time optimizing your server-side SQL.

Answer (score 0):

you could do it in BeforeGetRecords/OnGetData event handler or even elsewhere